# Change number of emacs ido display

Tags: emacs, elisp, ido

I think emacs ido display item number is a little less, how to change number of ido display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-h v ido-max-prospects`:

```
ido-max-prospects is a variable defined in `ido.el'.
Its value is 12

Documentation:
Upper limit of the prospect list if non-zero.
Zero means no limit for the prospect list.
For a long list of prospects, building the full list for the
minibuffer can take a non-negligible amount of time; setting this
variable reduces that time.

You can customize this variable.
```

---

```
(setq ido-max-prospects 5) ;; show 5 or fewer candidates in ido
```

---

BTW, I found this variable by looking through all the variables in `M-x customize-group ido`.